# Error: Can not find the element [#map_canvas]

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have an Ionic 4 app that uses `@ionic-native/google-maps`. I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Can not find the element [#map_canvas]
Error: Can not find the element [#map_canvas]
```

Here is info.page.html:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>Details</ion-title>
        <ion-buttons slot="start">
            <ion-button (click)="goBack()">
                <ion-icon slot="start" name="arrow-back"></ion-icon>
            </ion-button>
        </ion-buttons>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

    <ion-card *ngIf="info != undefined">
        <ion-card-header>
            <ion-card-subtitle>{{ info.nimi }}</ion-card-subtitle>
            <ion-card-title>{{ info.osoite }}</ion-card-title>
        </ion-card-header>

        <ion-card-content>
            {{ info.postinumero }} {{ info.kunta }}
            <br>
      {{ info.aukioloajat }}
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>

  <div id="map_canvas"></div>

</ion-content>
```

info.page.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LocationService } from '../location.service';
import { NavController, Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import {
  GoogleMaps,
  GoogleMap,
  GoogleMapsEvent,
  GoogleMapOptions,
  CameraPosition,
  MarkerOptions,
  Marker,
  Environment
} from '@ionic-native/google-maps';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tiedot',
  templateUrl: './info.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./info.page.scss'],
})
export class InfoPage implements OnInit {

  info: any;
  map: GoogleMap;

  constructor(public service: LocationService,
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    private platform: Platform) {
  }

  async ngOnInit() {
    this.map = this.service.getInfo();
    await this.platform.ready();
    await this.loadMap();
  }

  goBack() {
    this.navCtrl.back();
  }

  loadMap() {
    Environment.setEnv({
      'API_KEY_FOR_BROWSER_RELEASE': 'AIzaSyDhNkv1hIlt92x02Glsg9u_7u9GSwcOV5U',
      'API_KEY_FOR_BROWSER_DEBUG': 'AIzaSyDhNkv1hIlt92x02Glsg9u_7u9GSwcOV5U'
    })

    let mapOptions: GoogleMapOptions = {
      camera: {
        target: {
          lat: 43.0741904,
          lng: -89.3809802
        },
        zoom: 18,
        tilt: 30
      }
    }

    this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map_canvas', mapOptions);

    let marker: Marker = this.map.addMarkerSync({
      title: 'Ionic',
      icon: 'blue',
      animation: 'drop',
      position: {
        lat: 43.0741904,
        lng: -89.3809802
      }
    });
    marker.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_CLICK).subscribe(() => {
      alert('klikattu');
    })
  }

}

}
```

Also as a sidenote, can you provide an explanation as to what these error messages mean:

```
GET http://192.168.43.43:8100/config.xml 404 (Not Found)
```

and

```
[Browser][cordova.js][xhrStatusChangeHandler] Could not XHR config.xml: Not Found
```

Comment: Try calling `loadMap()` in `ngAfterViewInit` instead of `ngOnInit`.

Comment: `GoogleMaps.create` should be able to directly take an HTML element as the first param : since your view is encapsulated, maybe you should try getting the element, then feeding it to the function, instead of letting it getting the element thourgh its ID. But try @ConnorsFan's solution first !

Comment: suggestion didn't work, the problem still exists. @trichetriche can you provide me with the code on how to do this? Viewchild?

Comment: I added a Viewchild like this `@ViewChild('map_canvas') map_canvas: ElementRef;`, but it doesn't work

Comment: @aleksejjj you have to use `GoogleMaps.create(this.map_canvas.nativeElement, mapOptions);` if you try my solution !

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I dodged the issue by switching to `Angular Google Maps`.

Comment: hi @aleksejjj, is this resolved? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @rchau I could not resolve the issue myself, but you should try the tips in the answers people gave here. Instead of Ionic Native Maps I had to use Angular Google Maps instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was having the same issue. I have just added the styling to that div and it worked like a charm.

```
 <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%" id="map_canvas"></div>
```

All the code is same. Above method is tested.

Thanks! Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if the div has one (or more) dimension with 0 pixels. It happened to me too in the tabs template of Ionic. Just adding style fixes the problem. Also make sure that you are on a recent beta of the ionic native google maps plugin.

See: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-4-google-maps-plugin/139786/2

Answer (score 0):

Please check that the map div and the parent element have some height. CSS always treats percent values as a percentage of the parent element.

Oftentimes this problem is caused by 0px height being allocated. Think of it in this way, the map div was empty on init, it (and the parent element) would have 0px height. When we fill in the map stuff later, we will not see anything because the height 100% of the parent 0px is 0px. You will see the Error: Can not find the element [#map_canvas].

for example,

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-card style="height: 50%"> // 50% of the entire conent
        <div style="height: 100%;width: 100%" id="map_canvas"></div> // 100% of ion-card
    </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

Make sure the map div and the parent element (i.e. ion-card in the above example) have some height on init. You can set a fixed height for testing and it will prove my point.

```
<div style="height: 200px;" id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

**Ionic 4**

If you want to access Google Map in Modal Component use this piece of code

```
 GoogleMaps.create(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
```